# InvalidArgumentError Sentiment analyser with keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, sentiment-analysis, word-embedding

I have built a sentiment analyzer using Keras as a binary classification problem. I am using the Imdb dataset using GRU.
My code is:

```
# coding=utf-8
# ==========
#   MODEL
# ==========

# imports
from __future__ import print_function
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from datetime import timedelta
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras import regularizers
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding
from keras.layers import GRU, LeakyReLU, Bidirectional
from keras.datasets import imdb

#start a timer
start = timer()

# Hyperparameters
Model_Name = 'my_model.h5'
vocab_size = 5000
maxlen = 1000
batch_size = 512
hidden_layer_size = 2
test_split = 0.3
dropout = 0.1
num_epochs = 1
alpha = 0.2
validation_split = 0.25
l1 = 0.01
l2 = 0.01

# Dataset loading
print('Loading data...')
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(path="imdb.npz",
                                                      maxlen=maxlen)

print(len(x_train), 'train sequences')
print(len(x_test), 'test sequences')

# Data preprocessing
# Sequence padding
print('Pad sequences (samples x time)')
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=maxlen)
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print('x_test shape:', x_test.shape)

# Network building
print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, hidden_layer_size))
model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(hidden_layer_size, kernel_initializer='uniform', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=l1,l2=l2), dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=dropout,return_sequences=True)))
model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(hidden_layer_size, kernel_initializer='uniform', dropout=dropout, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=l1,l2=l2), recurrent_dropout=dropout)))
model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='uniform', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=l1,l2=l2)))

# Compile my model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')

# Fit the model
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epochs, validation_split=validation_split)
score, acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)

# Create a summary, a plot and print the scores of the model
model.summary()

print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)

# Save model architecture, weights, training configuration (loss,optimizer),
# and also the state of the optimizer, so you can resume where you stopped
model.save(Model_Name)
end = timer()
print('Running time:  ' + str(timedelta(seconds=(end - start))) + '  in Hours:Minutes:Seconds')
```

I keep receiving an Error message which I don't completely understand:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[502,665] = 5476 is not in [0, 5000)
[[Node: embedding_1/Gather = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, validate_indices=true, _device=/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0](embedding_1/embeddings/read, embedding_1/Cast)]]
```

Can anyone help me understand what causes this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error complains about a non-existent word index. That's because you are only limiting the number of Emedding features (i.e. there is a word with index 5476 which is not in the range `[0, 5000)`, which 5000 refers to the `vocab_size` you have set). To resolve this, you also need to pass the `vocab_size` as `num_words` argument of `load_data` function, like this:

```
... = imdb.load_data(num_words=vocab_size, ...)
```

This way you are limiting the words to the most frequent words (i.e. top `vocab_size` words with the most frequency in the dataset) with their indices in range `[0, vocab_size)`.